# Move an xml element group (including sub elements) up a specific hierarchy level with xslt

Tags: xslt

My goal is the move the element tag  to specific location.  Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my input

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
    <CHILD>
        <C.1>1</C.1>
        <C.2>something</C.2>
        <C.3>
            <A.1>AAA</A.1>
        </C.3>
    </CHILD>
    <CHILD.2>
        <ANOTHER.1>
            <ID_1>
                <PID.1>1</PID.1>
                <PID.2>
                    <CX.1>18</CX.1>
                    <CX.4>
                        <HD.1>HHH</HD.1>
                    </CX.4>
                    <CX.5>CCC</CX.5>
                </PID.2>
            </ID_1>
            <MOVEME>
                <ME.1>1</ME.1>
                <ME.2>
                    <M.1>10</M.1>
                    <M.2>some text string</M.2>
                </ME.2>
                <ME.3>MM</ME.3>
            </MOVEME>
            <ID_3/>
        </ANOTHER.1>
        <ANOTHER.2>
            <RC>
                <ORC.1>RR</ORC.1>
            </RC>
            <BR>
                <OBR.1>1</OBR.1>
                <OBR.2>
                    <EI.1>11</EI.1>
                    <EI.2>EIII</EI.2>
                </OBR.2>
            </BR>
            <BR.1/>
            <BR.2/>
        </ANOTHER.2>
    </CHILD.2>
    <CHILD.3/>
</ROOT>
```

Desired output

```
<ROOT>
    <CHILD>...</CHILD>
    <CHILD.2>
        <ANOTHER.1>
            <ID_1>...</ID_1>

            //MOVEME IS NOW GONE
            <ID_3/>
        </ANOTHER.1>
        <ANOTHER.2>...</ANOTHER.2>
    </CHILD.2>
    <CHILD.3/>
    //DESTINATION WITH ALL IT ELEMENTS AND CONTENTS
    <MOVEME>
        <ME.1>1</ME.1>
        <ME.2>
            <M.1>10</M.1>
            <M.2>some text string</M.2>
        </ME.2>
        <ME.3>MM</ME.3>
    </MOVEME>
</ROOT>
```

What I have so far it's producing an output but not quite correct.  It's including other elements belong to that specific tag as well.  I have also included the unwanted tags within the if statement, but it's still not working.

How do I avoid that?

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ROOT/*">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:if test="(name() != 'CHILD') and (name() != 'CHILD.2') and (name() != 'CHILD.3') and (name() != 'ANOTHER.2')" >
                <ZEI>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                </ZEI>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `<ZEI>` tags in your XSLT? Your desired output has no such element.

Comment: I'm sorry that's supposed to be <MOVEME> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your attempt is leading anywhere. The idea here is to add the "moved" node to where you want it, and prevent it being copied at its original location:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/ROOT">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <!-- add it to here -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="CHILD.2/ANOTHER.1/MOVEME"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove it from its original place -->
<xsl:template match="MOVEME"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```